# How to export plots from matplotlib with transparent background?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, transparency

I am using matplotlib to make some graphs and unfortunately I cannot export them without the white background.

[image: sample plot with solid white background]

In other words, when I export a plot like this and position it on top of another image, the white background hides what is behind it rather than allowing it to show through. How can I export plots with a transparent background instead?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Use the matplotlib `savefig` function with the keyword argument `transparent=True` to save the image as a png file.

```
In [28]: import numpy as np

In [29]: from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, savefig

In [30]: x = np.linspace(0,6,31)

In [31]: y = np.exp(-0.5*x) * np.sin(x)

In [32]: plot(x, y, 'bo-')
Out[32]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x3f29750>]            

In [33]: savefig('demo.png', transparent=True)
```

Result:
[image: demo.png]

Of course, that plot doesn't demonstrate the transparency.  Here's a screenshot of the PNG file displayed using the ImageMagick `display` command.  The checkerboard pattern is the background that is visible through the transparent parts of the PNG file.

[image: display screenshot]

Comment: Just for FYI for others using this.  `savefig` is under `matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: Thanks @RuiNian!  I added the appropriate imports to show how `np`, `plot` and `savefig` are imported.

Answer (score 1):

As a reminder, the plt.savefig() should be written before the plt.show(), otherwise, a transparent image will be created (without the actual plot).

For high-quality images:

```
plt.savefig('filename.png', format='png', dpi='600', transparent=True)
plt.show()
```