# How to change the background to transparent in matplotlib without saving the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I need to add a widget in a kivy GUI, but the plot looks very ugly with the default background. I tried to change the facecolor to black but it is still very monotonous and the edge of the plot cannot be changed. The background of the kivy canvas is good enough and how can I set the whole plot to be transparent without saving it as a file (as I need to update the plot constantly)?

```
    try:
        plt.plot(np.array(time_arr)[-10:], np.array(hum_data)[-10:])
    except IndexError:
        plt.plot(np.array(time_arr),np.array(hum_data))
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('moisture')
    plt.title('Real-time Moisture')
    plt.ylim((0, 1200))
    self.graph = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
    super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.ids.right.add_widget(self.graph)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.reload, 10)
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332349/matplotlib-how-to-make-the-background-transparent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: How to make the background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332349/matplotlib-how-to-make-the-background-transparent)