# remove white background from the matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph-visualization

I am trying to plot the transparent graph, but some boxes are appearing in the background and outer frame is not coming. How can I remove the white background from the plot and make it transparent and put outer frame?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.scatter(Neural_Net, y_test)
pyplot.xlabel('Actual', fontsize=15)
pyplot.ylabel('Predicted', fontsize=15)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857647/how-to-export-plots-from-matplotlib-with-transparent-background

Comment: Do you want to save the image?

Comment: Just to visualize. First, have to visualize it without white background.

Comment: somewhere in your code, you used the plt.style.use()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `matplotlib` `style` is `classic`

You can see available `matplotlib styles`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#To list all available styles, use:

print(plt.style.available)
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn', 'seaborn-bright', 'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-dark', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-deep', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-notebook', 'seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-pastel', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

To change back to the default white background:

```
plt.style.use('classic')
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to change to transparent background instead of white?

Comment: sure, just set transparent=True in plt.savefig()